# Add the number of (upvoted) answers to questions listed in the related section

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

A little number next to each question to be able to tell which questions have been answered.

Or in related only appear questions answered with upvotes already?

Answer (score 4):

This is a good idea. It will also improve the look and feel... Right now we have a list of lines on the right side, not very sexy.

Answer (score 1):

[Give extra reputation for answering a question with upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33635/give-extra-reputation-for-answering-a-question-with-upvotes) appears in the **Related** for this very question and has -3, so no, downvoted questions appear too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a color-code? Similar to the way the #-of-views text color changes (subtly) under questions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes).

So the most-viewed (or most-voted) Related questions float to the top, in a color-coded fashion. Color code could even be based on a combination of views, votes, answer status, etc. This might be more subtle than a number, but I think that's the beauty of it. It's an easier way to view the information.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth *considering* to include up to three numbers:

- Score of the question
- Number of upvoted answers (with a special colour if there is an accepted answer)
- Best score of an answer

Or at least pick the "most important" one, then display the others in a three-line tooltip.